# Will 5V from USB to i/o pins kill my arduino, or my laptop?

Tags: arduino

*You are in no way responsible for the effects of the advice you may give.*

I have a 5V source that I want to signal to my arduino to start some code when the source is on. I don't have the 5V source with me and want to test my code, and I happen to have an old usb cable handy. I think USB gives a fairly consistent 5V. But then again, I haven't taken E&M since 10 years ago in high school and have no idea what I'm talking about. Is 5V over the i/o pins from a USB cable likely to fry the board?

As a test I connected an active buzzer to the usb cable and it buzzed more quietly than it did when connected to the arduino pins. Then it stopped buzzing at all when connected to USB. Then I attached it to the arduino again and it buzzed loudly. Now my laptop is running slowly (but I'm running a numerical simulation in the background, and it could be that it has hit a complicated calculation and the slow performance is due to that) and I wonder if I did damage to my motherboard.

I wont have access to a multimeter until Monday so I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you short it out,  both should be fine. Don't put the arduino gpio in output low mode to avoid that. A series limiting resistor of 10k would helo. Make sure you connect the grounds together or it won't work right.

If you are concerned, an opto coupler would work to isolate the two devices.

Comment: A series limiting resistor is also important if the Arduino is not powered and the USB port is. Anywhere between 1K and 10K should work fine.

Comment: An opto would be better for that though.

Answer (score 1):

The USB standard calls for voltage to be 5V +0.25 −0.60, so from 4.4V to 5.25V. I would check your USB voltage to make sure it is not over the input voltage of the arduino, but assuming that it should be fine.

Comment: No, it's  +- 5%, 0.25V  each way, not -0.6V